# regexp to find hashtags

Tags: regex, matlab

This is for Matlab. I have a tweet and I need to find what the hashtags say. I know I can isolate and save to a variable everything that starts with a '#' and ends with a ' ' using regexp. But, when I use

```
    tweet = 'it is fun to post on #stackoverflow, really #itis';
    regexp(tweet,'#(\w+)','tokens','once')
    ans = 
        'stackoverflow'
```

I only get the first #. How would I make it so that I could get the "itis" # as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
regexp(tweet,'#(\w+)','match')
ans = 
'#stackoverflow'    '#itis'
```

However, it seems as if you know more about Regex than I do, so I guess you know how to get rid of the `#`'s in the string.

Answer (score 4):

[`once`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_options) returns only the first match....  Drop that if you don't want that.

Comment: When I do this, it only displays the cell arrays (ie. {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}). I need the actual text.

Comment: ... which is what `'tokens'` means.... [pick the output that you want](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#bsyicm1-5), it's all in the docs...

Comment: So which would I use in this case?

Comment: ... wait what? You don't know what output you want?

Comment: What would the script be if I wanted to have both of the hashtag handles show up?

Answer (score 0):

According to the matlab documentation, you need to remove the 'once'.
Source:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html

Comment: Correct but, when this is removed it doesn't show me the text after the #. This is what I need help doing.